# Is there a keyboard shortcut to insert an @username in the comment box?

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies

Assume you are typing a comment and trying to reply to a user by typing "@". A menu pops up:

[image]

We can click on that menu to insert the `@username` string. We can also type it out. Is there a keyboard shortcut to accept one of the user names that are displayed?

If not I'd like to request that feature. Moving the mouse is tedious. Some user names are hard to type.

It could be <kbd>Ctrl-[1-9]</kbd> to accept the Nth user name shown.

Comment: write `@{first_letter}` and then hit `TAB`. (Hit `TAB` multiple times if you have a list of names starting with the phrase you entered)

Comment: @juergend good. Almost as good as Visual Studio. We need camel-humps auto-complete for user names! :) Seriously, that's the answer to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Most of the time just one letter is enough, occasionally you have to type the first two letters of the name. CamelCase auto-complete seems like overkill.

Comment: @juergend , Why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

As @juergen's comment above,

> write @{first_letter} and then hit TAB. (Hit TAB multiple times if you have a list of names starting with the phrase you entered)

Comment: PS: was going to post a question for such [tag:feature-request], got this question and found answer as comment. So posting it as answer...